# How to open page directly in Ionic 4 from url

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a project in Ionic 4, when I do `ionic serve` it runs at `localhost:8100/`

Now when it loads home page, the URL is `localhost:8100/home`, if I open contact page the URL becomes `localhost:8100/contact`.

When I try to copy the above URL and hit, then it says -

> Sorry, this page doesn't exist. Please check the URL or go back a page.

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Did you get a solution to this? I am facing the same issue in my Ionic web app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments this is happening because your server does not support fallback. So when you enter a url manually, the server is trying to find that page, but you only have *index.html* in your app because of Client side routing.

> If the app uses the Angular router, you must configure the server to
>   return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file
>   that it does not have.

The configuration is specific to your server or cloud platform. You can check [Angular deployment](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) for more info.

Comment: I have done that, but now it goes to index page and not does not open that url page what do i do now ?

Comment: The issue in your case might be that you are deploying to a subfolder _/qanda/pwa_. Are you running _ionic build --prod -- --base-href /qanda/pwa/_ ?

Comment: No, only ionic build --prod, I am travelling at the moment, I'll test it in next 8 hours as you have guided and let you know

Answer (score 1):

This regularly should not happen and you can't do anything for this. Try to upgrade your ionic to the latest with nodejs since the error my be from currupted project creation. Then after update create a new project and it should go good.

Comment: it is working offline but when i am uploading it to my server it is not working, any guesses why, here is the link u can check - https://sapphireprofits.com/qanda/pwa/

Comment: It is working well.I think its related to your browser since it 100% working without any problem.